How to convert solar energy into compact cooling system?
I have started researching thermoelectric effect today and I have some questions.
Can you have double-sided peltiers? I want to apply electric current to one of those, so that it will be either cold or hot on either sides. Is that possible and how efficient is that?
Let's say I have a solar blanket that turns photons into electric energy. And I want to cool the other side (or both) of the blanket. Is it efficient to use many peltiers attached in parallel or can I use something that is more efficient, like a gas or a liquid? It should also be quite compact.
I came across the thermoelectric effect, because I wanted to turn the Sun's heat into cold. But I assume it isn't possible yet, because you have to concentrate heat first and then you could use an absorption refrigeration system, but I don't see how that's compact. Can it be though?
I basically wanted to make a tent, maybe, that absorbs the heat from the sun and makes it cold on the inside? Would that be possible on a small scale?
Thank you. I hope I have coherently expressed my concern on the subject. Feel free to ask anything if I've not been clear enough.

Peltier coolers are horrendously inefficient. You are better off running a fan to keep cool.

Heating or cooling both sides of an object is easy. You heat or cool the object.
A Peltier cooler is different. The Peltier cooler starts out warm. It pushes some heat from one side to the other. One side heats up and the other cools down.
You might think of putting the hot sides of two Peltier coolers together. Now you have a double cooler that is cold on both side. Unfortunately, it gets hotter and hotter in the middle. The heat has nowhere to go but right back to the cold sides.
An air conditioner is similar. It moves heat around. It blows hot air out one side and cold air out the other. You vent the hot side outdoors and keep the cold air inside. If you put both sides indoors, the hot and cold air mixes and you don't get any benefit. It is worse that that. It takes energy to run an air conditioner. That energy becomes heat and is added to the hot side. So running an air conditioner with no vent would make the room hotter.
A Peltier cooler has the same problem. You get more heat on the hot side than cooling on the cold side. You generally have to provide a place for the heat to go.
Here is an example of a Peltier cooler used to make big ice crystals. It is used in combination with a freezer (which is an air conditioner in a box). The cold side of the Peltier cooler cools the ice. The hot side warms up the freezer. The freezer takes the heat outside. A DIY Recipe for Giant Hexagonal Ice Crystals.
If you want to see more on how Peltier coolers work, see Make Electricity Go Round and Round - The Thermoelectric Effect

"It blows cold air out one side and cold air out the other."  One of those "cold"s should be "hot".  : )

okay, say I have a solar-powered "blanket" that I want to cool on both sides. I can't just stick giant fans on the sides. How do I make it cold and power it using solar energy, without using Peltier coolers? Is there maybe some liquid solution? Cause everywhere I've looked I can't really find a compact solution to the problem other than TECs, but from what I get: they're very inefficient.
